# Generating customized clock using Image Button and TextView

Tags: android, onfling

I'm new to Android and have been stuck with this issue for sometime now. I'm trying to implement a customized clock in my app using imageviews on top and bottom of fields which shows the number-data of the hour or minute. What I have so far accomplished of doing was implementing a touchevent on these imageviews to either increase my time or to decrease my time.

One feature that I am trying to add into this is to have my textviews recognize "fling" motion of the user and go increasing/decreasing based on the direction of the fling.

To do this, I have been searching on the web for these "fling" implementations of which I have found to be the following:

```
minute.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    minute.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
                    Log.d("fling", "down");
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    minute.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                    Log.d("fling", "Flinged.");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            return false;
        }
    });
```

which, I have put into the onTouchEvent of my `minute` textview field.

With or without the `minute.dispatchTouchEvent` lines within my onDown and onFling methods, I do not get any logs in my logcat, from which I assume that this gesturemotion is not being dispatched to my minute field.

How do I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance for help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved via using [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) to simulate the a digital clock.

To my app's requirements, I set the wrap to false and min and max value to be reversed to have the "fling down" action simulate incrementing the desired time.